# I keep geting this error related with Netmiko when sending send_config_set(), but send_comand() works?

Tags: python-3.x, automation, cisco, netmiko

[image: Output error]

This is my simple code:

```
import netmiko

connection = netmiko.ConnectHandler(
    ip = "192.168.122.100",
    device_type = "cisco_ios",
    username="dule",
    password = "cisco"
)

output = connection.send_command("sh ip inter br")

connection.send_command("conf t")

conf_command = ['int loop 0', 'ip address 1.1.1.1 255.255.255.255']

output = connection.send_config_set(conf_command)
print(output)
connection.disconnect()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in my case was privilege level, you should put **username 'cisco' privilege 15**